# shortcut to run concrete test

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I can run the whole Junit test using:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>

But how I can run a single test? Using the mouse I click on concrete method and `Run As -> Junit test`

anyone know shortcut for this case ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? I can't run a single method of a JUnit class test, even using the mouse...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, T runs one test method if the caret is on the method name.

[image]

Comment: Very inconvenient for the caret to have to sit on the test method and for the file to be the current active one. What if the test case uses an external file and you're tweaking that file as you keep retesting it? FrBaBe's answer below addresses this, because when you run the test case using the right click once, that particular test shows in the history, and when you run it once from the run menu button (or debug), and you have it configured to always run the last configuration, a simple F11 keeps relaunching it - no matter what you have open.

Answer (score 16):

I find the "<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>" gives me trouble sometimes, sometimes what I *think* is the last executed command is not always and sometimes I end up running something I did not mean to. Also when doing TDD you rerun the tests so often and sometimes want to rerun the test from one project for a while, then you are on to the next project and want to start running its tests. Or you might be focusing on a specific area and only want to run a single unit test few a while. In this case I find I would like to simply rerun my last tests often and I find "<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>" to be a bit cumbersome.

So what I do is "Windows" > "Preferences" then click "General" > "Keys". Sort the table by "Command" and scroll down until you find "Rerun JUnit Test - Failures First" and "Rerun JUnit Test". Click on one of those and set the "Binding" field to whatever keyboard shortcut you want to use. Personally I set "Rerun JUnit Test" to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> so that its similar to refreshing a browser (plus this give me the quick and easy save/rerun combo of hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you sir for a very good practical advice.

Answer (score 5):

If you run the single test method as you described it will be the last entry in the "Run history". To run the test again you can simply click on the run button in the toolbar or press 'Ctrl-F11'.

Comment: @Hugo Just tried in Helios (Ctrl+F11) using the Java perspective and it works for me. Curious?!

Comment: Hugo, you have to run it once using the run/debug button for F11 to start working. You also have to have set up in the preferences to always launch the last configuration.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>F11</kbd> run test and activate window console.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>  run test and activate window JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Years later, for me, what works is ALT+R+T+Enter which would run the last ran test whether it's a specific method or class. CTL-F11 for me only runs the last junit class even if the last run was a specific method of that junit class.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - runs just one unit-test method. Set the caret to the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OrderOfExecution {

    @Test
    public void test2()
    {
        System.out.println("Test 2");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Test 1");
    }
  }
```

If you want to run test2 only,   Just select method name test2,  and run as-->JUnit.
It will run the test2 test only.